# Modulus operation

Tags: math, modulo

When you do division operation, the number that is being divided  is called the dividend, and the number that it is dividing is called the divisor.

**Question:** When you do modulo operation, is there a defined naming for the two numbers involved in the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this subject. If you're asking about the following process, I'll explain.

```
x,y and z ∈ Z
x = y(modz)
```

- Remainder => y
- Divisor => z
- "x" can be any number that gives a remainder of "y" when divided by "z".

Comment: Yes, so [dividend]/[devisor]=[quotent], [dividend]%[divisor]=remainder.